# FOR in C++ (Limiting the loops!)

Tags: c++, for-loop, integer

I've a problem with a simple FOR in C++ (I'm beginner in C++).

Can any body tell my what is wrong in this code, when I run this code, the numbers 51 to 349 is showing!!

But I want to get numbers 1 to 349. Better 1 to n (n is about 10,000,000)

```
for (int k=1; k != 350; k++) cout << k << endl;
```

Also, I've tried this code, but nothing changed!

```
for (int k=1; k <= 350; k++) cout << k << endl;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Probably your console is limiting you to 300 lines visible? What happens when you stop at 300?

Comment: [Works fine](http://ideone.com/SGMpF3).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem may be that your console is set to only display the last 300 lines.  If you are using windows right click on it, go to properties, and adjust the buffer size.  If that doesn't work experiment.  Try changing the upper and lower bounds of the loop to see what happens.